# WCF : Service call failed: 400Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, jquery

I am using asp.net 3.5. I have developed the WCF Service. I try to call the WCF Service form JQUERY, But I am getting the error as

Service call failed: 400 Bad Request

MY Code is as follows:-

IService:-

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    //[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    CommandStatus getCommandStatus(string Id, string UnitNumber, string UnitType);
}
```

Service :-

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public CommandStatus getCommandStatus(string Id, string UnitNumber, string UnitType)
    {
        CommandStatus objCommandStatus = new CommandStatus();
        CommandsBLL objCommandsBLL = new CommandsBLL();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = objCommandsBLL.getCommandStatus(Convert.ToInt32(Id), UnitNumber, Convert.ToInt32(UnitType));

        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            objCommandStatus.ID = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IOMH_ID"]);
            objCommandStatus.UnitType = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IOMH_UnitType"]);
        }

        return objCommandStatus;
    }
}
```

Web.Config file is

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and Final my Jquery call is

```
var ID = 10;
    var UnitNumber = '10001';
    var UnitType = 1;

    function CallService() {
       var input =
        {
                ID: "10",
                UnitNumber: "10001",
                UnitType: "1"
        };

        //alert(JSON.stringify(input));
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:2878/Mtel_Profiler/Service.svc/getCommandStatus",
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            success: function (userViewModel) {
                var user = userViewModel;
                alert(user);
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                ServiceFailed(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(msg)
    {
        alert('Sucess');
        return false;
    }

    function ServiceFailed(result)
    {
        alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
        return false;
    }
```

Can any one help to resolved this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if you have already done this, Can you check if your service run fine using wcftestclient?

Comment: Yes, My service is running fine with wcftestclient. But When I call using jquery it is giving error. any help.

Comment: Do you know if its returning large dataset? if thats the case it might be because of limit in config, you can override it with - maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"

Comment: One more thing is you can make this param true - <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" /> to get Exception details which will help to solve the problem.